# Image swap on CSS 3D transform flip

Tags: html, css, css-animations

http://jsfiddle.net/RtTPU/

I am trying to swap the image "Adam" to "Adam-flipped" on hover, so once the image is hovered over it will swap as it's flipped yet it's not working. Is it possible to do this entirely in CSS?

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <img src="http://adamginther.com/assets/img/adam.jpg" alt="Adam">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="http://adamginther.com/assets/img/adam-flipped.jpg" alt="Adam" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.self-portrait {
    border-radius: 400px;
    width: 50%;
}


/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue with one of the provided answers?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because it lacks the prefixes for `transform` and `backface-visibility`. Plus you have to tell the children of `.flipper` to retain the 3d transforms applied to it and calculate the combined effects automatically by `transform-style: preserve-3d` (needs prefixes, too).

A second problem: You have to set an explicit `width` on `.flip-container` or `.flipper` to ensure the image flips around the center y axis. Leaving it on `auto` results in different levels of quirkyness on different screen sizes, though.

Note that my code samples contain only the webkit prefix for brevity. Hope this gets the point across.

Relevant changes:

```
.flip-container {
  ...
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper {
  ...
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.front, .back {
   ...
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

See all the changes on the fixed version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/RtTPU/6/

Version with less verbose markup and sanitized css styles: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/6Je6r/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think here is all you want. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RtTPU/1/)

```
.flip-container:hover .back{
    z-index : 10;
}
.back{
    z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need prefixes for the transform property.

Also .flip-container.hover is useless, and perspective needs units:

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

[corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RtTPU/2/)